# DataGridRow background changes upon selection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

After carefully looking around, I'm only finding people who don't know how to change a row's background upon selection, whereas I'm trying to find out how to prevent it from changing colors when it's selected.
I have a DataGrid with dynamically generated columns (which makes styling somewhat of a challenge for me), which hold MyObjects, an `object` with the property `IsDeleted`. This property (as it suggests) keeps track of whether or not this MyObject is deleted or not and thus if it's background needs to be red.

```
<Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDeleted}" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="red"/>
      </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

However, when I select a row that is deleted, the 'background' will change to blue (obviously, because it is selected) which makes it somewhat hard to identify deleted MyObjects. I have read some suggestions with `Property="OverrideDefault.SelectionBackground" Value="Red"` and such, but those didn't seem to work for me.

I'm probably overlooking something obvious, but please keep in mind the DataGrid is generated dynamically, so the statements have to be *somewhat* dynamic too

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using ColorAnimation:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomDataGridRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}"/>
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Border x:Name="DGR_Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="White">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal_Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DGR_Border"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                                    To="Transparent" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DGR_Border"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                                    To="LightGray" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <DataGridCellsPresenter ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

When 'Normal_Selected' color it with wahtever color you want.

Comment: pasting this into my xaml file just made the program crash. I honestly can't really tell what's going on here either, so I wouldn't have a clue on how to fix it ..

Comment: Remove x:Key="CustomDataGridRowStyle", it's should wotk